# How can I read config schema from a config entity?

Tags: 8, configuration

I need to read the schema definition from a config entity, which is located in config/schema. For example the schema from a node type defined in node.schema.yml:

```
node.type.*:
  type: config_entity
  label: 'Content type'
  mapping:
    name:
      type: label
      label: 'Name'
    type:
      type: string
      label: 'Machine-readable name'
    description:
      type: text
      label: 'Description'
    help:
      type: text
      label: 'Explanation or submission guidelines'
    new_revision:
      type: boolean
      label: 'Whether a new revision should be created by default'
    preview_mode:
      type: integer
      label: 'Preview before submitting'
    display_submitted:
      type: boolean
      label: 'Display setting for author and date Submitted by post information'
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found, it can be done by using **config.typed** service:

```php
$typed_config_manager = \Drupal::service('config.typed');
$node_type_definition = $typed_config_manager->getDefinition('node.type.*');
```